# Split Matrix according to a value of an index-vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a nx3 matrix as the following

```
1 x1 y1 
2 x2 y2 
2 x3 y3 
1 x4 y4 
   : 
   : 
1 (or2) xn yn
```

this is signal coming from two channels but recorded in the same matrix.
I would like to splitt the matrix into two matrices to be

```
M1 = 

1 x1 y1 
1 x4 y4 
: 
: 
1 xi yi 

M2=

2 x2 y2 
2 x3 y3 
: 
: 
2 xj yj
```

Comment: Please edit the question for better readability. I have already edited the first section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical indexig:

```
% generate some input data:
N = 10;
val = randi([1,2],[1,10]);
x = rand(1,N);
y = rand(1,N);
in = [val;x;y]';

% select all values where the value in the first column is 1
M1 = in(in(:,1)==1,:);
% select all values where the value in the first column is 2
M2 = in(in(:,1)==2,:);
```

Comment: what matrices do you have? nx3 or 3xn?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: in your question you start with "I have a 3xn matrix" and then you show a nx3 matrix. what are you working with?

Comment: it was a mistake, it is indeed nx3 matrix what I have

Comment: i changed the answer. please also correct your question